# SPARQL query to get subjects linked to object 2 that are not linked to object 1, using IF or NOT EXISTS or any other way?

Tags: if-statement, sparql, option-type, not-exists

I hope you are doing well.
Here is the basic structure of my graph database. Components have estimation methods, estimation methods have parameters and parameters have data sources.

```
c -> em -> p -> ds
```

Where,

```
c stands for components
em stands for estimation methods
p stands for parameters
ds stands for data sources
```

I am able to query individuals in the structured format like this:

```
SELECT ?c ?em ?p ?ds WHERE {

    ?c wb:hasEstimationMethod ?em.
 
        OPTIONAL {
            ?em wb:hasParameter ?p.
            
            OPTIONAL{
                ?p wb:hasDataSource ?ds.
            }
        }
    }
```

I use OPTIONAL clause because there is a possibility that estimation method might not have any parameters and similarly parameters might not have any data sources.

However, there are few cases where, for example, an estimation method is unknown but we know the parameter. So for example in that case, components will directly have parameters and I would prefer to have blank for estimation methods. So here is the output I would like to have,

| c | em | p | ds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| component-1 | estimation method-1 | parameter-1 | data source-1 |
| component-2 |  | parameter-2 | data source-2 |
| component-3 |  | parameter-3 |  |

If you notice the last two rows have have missing info which is what I want to have in my output if that is the case. In other words, I want to skip a step in the hierarchical structure.

So my question is, how can I first query `?c wb:hasEstimationMethod ?em` but if it does not have any value, I want to tell SPARQL to use query `?c wb:hasParameter ?p` and similarly if that has no value as well, do `?c wb:hasDataSource ?ds` ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I am not using the right terminology. Have a wonderful day :)

Comment: for alternative paths where you need the intermediate nodes you have to use `UNION` operator.

Comment: proper sample data would be nice to reproduce it.

Comment: @UninformedUser hello thanks for your reply, sorry this is my first question on stack overflow, how can I put a sample data to my question that people can access?

Is there a way to use alternative path using UNION operator only if the usual path returns no value? Thank you for your time!

Comment: what do you mean by "only if'? The second alternative would be a totally different pattern, or not? Like `{?c a wb:component . ?c ?c wb:hasParameter ?p. OPTIONAL{
                ?p wb:hasDataSource ?ds.
            }}` - indeed, it only works if you can distinguish a component from the estimation method, like i simulated with a type `wb:component` - but this something good modeling does use anyways

Comment: yes the 2nd alternative is a different pattern but I still want to show the output in the same table as I displayed above. For example, for a component get all estimation methods, for an estimation method get parameters, and for a parameter get data sources. But there is a possibility that a parameter is directly linked to component or if a data source is directly linked to component. In that case, I want to have those intermediate values (estimation methods and/or parameters) as blanks in the table. And yes I do have a way to distinguish components from estimation methods and so on.

Comment: but all not bound variables will become a blank node. `SELECT ... WHERE { {} UNION {{?c a wb:component . ?c ?c wb:hasParameter ?p. OPTIONAL{                 ?p wb:hasDataSource ?ds.             }}}}` - in the second alternative `?em` will of course be empty.